# updated nested Immutable in immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, reselect

how can i update a nested immutable Map item without mutatiling the whole tree ?

example :

```
var tree = Map({
 branch1:Map([]),
 branch2:Map({ 1: Map({id:1,value:'hello'}) }),
});
```

how can i update tree.branch2.1.value ?

will this cause branch1 to get a new copy ?

i'm using this in a Reactjs Redux app. since i'm also using selectors, i want to change value of `branch2` without changin branch1 also, so that selectors wonnt recalculate again

Comment: see https://github.com/reactjs/reselect -- a nice library for creating memoized selectors so that you don't have to worry about them recalculating when the state updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing values in an Immutable.js object will **always** return a completely new object instead of mutating it. That's essentially the whole point of the library. If you are worried about unnecessary re-renders based on other aspects of your state changing, you should use the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method to ensure that your components only update when the *value* of that part of the app state changes, and not simply when it is a new object.

For your case, it would make the most sense to use the [setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) method for Immutable maps.

```js
tree.setIn(['branch2', 1, 'value'], 'newValue');
```